# Creating a sidecar with KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am looking to create a sidecar container while using `KubernetesPodOperator`. I am seeing options to create `init container` with `pod_mutation_hook` but I am not seeing an option to create a `sidecar`. If I create a `init container` that has to complete before I can start my actual container, but I don't want that and need the sidecar to be running as long as my main container in the port is alive.

Answer (score 0):

A sidecar is a container than supports the main container. With Composer the main container is airflow. Composer is a managed product and does not need additional support. Keep in mind that you can always increase the machine type if you need more processing power.

If you are looking forward to use the sidecar with pods that you would create with the KubernetesPodOperator you can have the sidecar defined in the Airflow settings file using pod_mutation_hook.

You can use [pod_mutation_hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/kubernetes.html#pod-mutation-hook), this is defined in airflow_local_settings.